# "This device isn‘t eligible for the requested build" while trying to install iOS 9.2 beta 4

Tags: ios, ipad, itunes

I'm trying to install iOS 9.2 beta 4 on my iPad, but I'm getting the *The iPad 'Carl's iPad' could not be restored. This device isn't eligible for the requested build* error. I followed the Apple support [article](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201442), but with no results.

Before trying to install iOS 9.2, I registered the device's `UDID` in **Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles**, as instructed in Apple's [guide](http://adcdownload.apple.com/Documentation/Beta_Software_Installation_Guides/iOS_beta_Software_Installation_Guide.pdf). I then launched the most recent version of iTunes (12.3.1.23), clicked `option` + **Restore iPad...**, and chose the correct file (`iPad3,3_9.2_13C75_Restore.ipsw`).

The iPad is the 3rd generation iPad (A1430, Wi-Fi + Cellular).

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the answer on the [Apple dev forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/26645?answerId=89344022#89344022).

The trick is to download and install beta 3 first and then update OTA (within Settings on the device) to beta 4. Beta 3 isn't listed on the Apple site, the URL can easily constructed based on the beta 4 file name. The build number of Beta 3 is 13C71. For example, the link to the iPod touch image is:

[adcdownload.apple.com/iOS/iOS_9.2_beta_3/iOS_9.2_beta_3__iPod_touch_5th_generation__13C71.zip](https://developer.apple.com/unauthorized/)

Comment: You cannot download old beta versions by constructing a link. It says that you don't have permission to do so. I'm downloading it in a different way. I just did a Google search.

Comment: Odd. I was able to download the old versions directly a week ago, but (as you noticed) not any more.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an issue with the iOS Provisioning/Licensing servers due to which the beta is not signed at the moment. I am getting the same issue trying to install the beta on an iPad Air 2.